# In C++, is it possible for child classes of an abstract class to take different parameters for the same fuctions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Sorry if I didn't phrase the question well enough, but say the code looks something like this:

```
   Class Parent
    {
public:
    virtual void Sit() = 0;
    }

    Class Child1 : public Parent
    {
public:
    virtual void Sit(obj* chair) override;
    }

    Class Child2 : public Parent
    {
public:
    virtual void Sit(obj* bench) override;
    }
```

Basically, I need my objects to inherit from the same abstract class but they need to take in different parameters for the same functions as they have different behavior, I imagine something like this is possible but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Once you have a different parameter set, it's not the same function.it's called function overloading and you have both versions.

Comment: This is not possible if you want call the function through a pointer to the base class.

Comment: Your example does not demonstrate taking different parameters. Both `Child1::Sit()` and `Child2::Sit()` take an `obj*` as the parameter. If you change the declaration of `Parent::Sit()` to `virtual void Sit(obj*) = 0`, then you have no issue in this particular example.

Comment: use polymorphisme

Comment: If you really do need different parameter types, then you should ask yourself why the function exists at the `Parent` level. If you cannot meaningfully call `Sit()` through a `Parent*` (because you cannot know which parameters would be appropriate), then it is unlikely that `Sit()` should be defined in `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you're trying to do, not quite. If you are using `override`, then you must override from the parent exactly. Otherwise it's not an override, and your compiler should complain.

You could make Parent::Sit() take a `void *`, and then the implementations in your child classes could assume, although that's kind of dangerous.

If the arguments to Sit() at least all inherit from a common base class, then you could define it that way. That's a little less bad than starting with `void *`.